# XML refering best practice

Tags: xml, reference, nodes, identifier

I am writing an XML-sheet in which I manage a list of document types and a list of a document collection. It currently looks like this:

```
<collection>
    <types>
        <type id="T001">CD</type>
        <type id="T002">Drawing</type>
        <type id="T003">Book</type>
        <type id="T004">Photo</type>
        <type id="T005">Letter</type>
    </types>
    <languages>
        <lang id="EN">English</taal>
        <lang id="FR">French</taal>
    </languages>
    <documents>
        <document>
            <type>T001</type>
            <lang>EN</lang>
        </document>
        <document>
            <type>T003</type>
            <lang>FR</lang>
        </document>
        <document>
            <type>T001</type>
            <lang>EN</lang>
        </document>
        <document>
            <type>T002</type>
            <lang>EN</lang>
        </document>
    <documents>
</collection>
```

I manage the types and languages lists within the XML sheet instead of using DTD entities so I can query those using XSL / Xpath.

As you can see the  and  elements are used in two different cases: in the first lists (types / languages) I use them as identifier, and later on I use them as reference element, but with the same node name. I am thinking it's not very neat using the same node name for both the identifier and the refering element.
What would be another, neater way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just a matter of convention. Personally, I would change it to:

```
<documents>
    <document>
        <typeRef>T001</type>
        <langRef>EN</lang>
        ...
```

Or:

```
<documents>
    <document type="T001" lang="EN">
    ...
```

Comment: It's not just a matter of convention; index relation between *document* and *type* elements can't be modelized within DTD syntax, as ID and IDREF are attribute types.